# Latex highlighting error for lstinline

Tags: listings, texmaker, editors, syntax-highlighting

it has been quite a while that I have this problem and I have searched everywhere online and couldn't find a solution.

The problem is latex syntax highlighting doesn't work after this line:

```
\newcommand{\psins}[1]{\colorbox[rgb]{0.8,0.8,1}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black}]|#1|}}
```

Everything (almost) after this line is written in the same color. I am using Texmaker on Linux Mint 17. I even compiled texmaker to have the most recent version (4.5) and hoping that it would fix, but no avail. Also, I have read about the bug here https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=322154 and looked at my `latex.xml` (which is located at `/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax`) and saw that it's the same as the corrected version in this bug report.

It's still not much of a big problem since I am using `\include` and doing my writing on different files, but still I was wondering and very curious about what causes this problem.

Thanks

---

complete tex file to reproduce the bug:

(by the way, that problem didn't occur on this question's code block)

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}     % for bg and fg colors
\usepackage{soul}       
\setul{1pt}{}                       % to underline by \ul{}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\definecolor{techy}{rgb}{0.65,0.85,0.65}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true,frame=single}
\lstdefinestyle{DOS}
{
     backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.34,0,0.34},
     basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{white},
     commentstyle=\color{green}
}

\lstdefinelanguage{pshell}
{
     morecomment=[l]{\#}
}


\newcommand{\psins}[1]{\colorbox[rgb]{0.8,0.8,1}
{\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black}]|#1|}}

\newcommand{\nottez}[2]{
\begin{center}
   \colorbox{mygray}{ 
   \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
   {\large \textbf{#1}} \vspace*{3pt} \par #2
   \end{minipage}}
\end{center}}

\newcommand{\technet}[2]{
\begin{center}
   \colorbox{techy}{ 
   \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
   {\large \color{Sepia}\textbf{#1}} \vspace*{3pt} \par #2
   \end{minipage}}
\end{center}}

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{-4pt}{\setul{2pt}{}\LARGE\ul}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3mm}{9mm}

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

%\include{mstrch3}
now everything after lstinline is in the same color.

\end{document}
```

Comment: it would be easier to answer your question if you provides a complete small document showing the problem but in general verbatim-like commands such as listings can not be used in the argument of another command 9or only with severe restrictions.

Comment: good to know that such commands are not friendly as arguments of another commands. If I know that this is not fixable or too complex to fix, I would look for other methods to highlight text in the typesetted document. But I think that it's the similar to the bug report (on the link in the question) therefore thinking that it could be fixed, just that I am not skilled enough to do it myself.

Comment: It is fixable (see the listings documentation) but you need to give an example, the code you have posted doesn't use lstinline at all so is no use at all in debugging your problem. Surely you can copy a small example from the document where it fails and make this fragment fail, it is hard to debug unseen code.

Comment: I tried `\psins{abc < *.* dir } now everything after lstinline is in the same color.` but the `now everything...` was in black so you really need to provide an example.

Comment: Sorry that apparently I haven't explained the problem correctly. What I wanted to say is that everything works perfect after typeset -- that's the compiling runs without problem, and I get my pdf file with everything typeset and highlighted correctly. The problem is however in exactly above code block. That is, if you copy paste it into any latex editor, you'd notice that after line starting with `\newcommand{\psins}`  syntax color doesn't change. Compiling is not necessary to reproduce the bug -- just copy paste the above code into any latex editor which has syntax highlight feature

Comment: No absolutely not. syntax highlighting is a feature of the editor the behaviour of different editors, what they highlight what colours they use and how much they are confused by listings is just a feature of the editor setup. In the editor I use, [it looks like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d6gok.png) which seem OK to me

Comment: I would put all your definitions into `mydefs.sty` and then just have `\usepackage{mydefs}` in your preamble that keeps all such things out of the way of your document editing.

Comment: Ok. I didn't see the `\begin{document} \end{document}` part. **Could you please make sure** that the text inside `\begin{document} \end{document}` is in the color as it should be (I don't see that part in the picture). By the way, I am using Texmaker, and actually I posted this info in the question part above. I think this is not editor-centric problem, because of my google searches. Apparently it happened in Vim too. That's why I said any editor should produce this bug.

Comment: .sty files actually seems to be a good option. I'll try that and post about the result soon.

Comment: there are no real editors other than emacs:-)  [Full buffer image as requested](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LFNbm.png)

Comment: thanks for the full image. Seems like you're right about emacs :)  haven't tried/used it yet though.

Comment: Using style file kinda solves the problem. But the root of the problem still exists -- that's, now inside .sty file syntax highlighting stops working properly after that `\lstinline`. I think I can make a separate .sty file just for the command that includes `\lstinline`, and the problem should disappear. But still this doesn't tell me why the problem happens in the first place.  Thanks a lot David for the suggestions. Learned some new stuff. I have to go now, and will be able to check forum tomorrow.

Comment: FWIW, proper syntax highlighting seems to be restored after the first occurrence of `\end{listings}`.

Comment: Also reported at https://raphaelpour.de/2018/02/13/avoid-wrong-texmaker-highlighting-with-lstinput/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used the following workaround to avoid it

```
\newcommand{\lstinlineProxy}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}
```

Then in my code, I use `lstinlineProxy` instead of `lstinline`. That way, texstudio is not aware of the usage of `lstinline`.